Extending an image past the navigation bar
I'm building a static website out of html and CSS (JS if I really need it) and in the navbar I want there to be a logo in the center that drops down past it a bit (ex. https://usiscreamingeagles.com/). It's a circle logo on a responsive topnav. Can I get some help on making that extend down?
Below is the existing code. Right now it just expands the navbar with the size of the image like you would expect it to usually do:


.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(9, 120, 128);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}


/* If screen is less than 600px, create hamburger*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#schedule">Schedule</a>
    <a href="#home">
      <img src="files\img.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>




"a logo in the center that drops down past it a bit... It's a circle logo on a responsive topnav" nothing as you described is visible on the provided link. Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mre] of a specific issue you've encountered.

PS (offtopic?): The JS is not good, use className  only when you're creating brand new Elements. Otherwise, use myTopnav.classList.toggle("expanded") < as you can see, you only need to toggle one specific class. Style it in CSS accordingly. That one line is all you need inside the click handler. Also, avoid using inline on* handlers like onclick="myFunction()". JS should be in one place only and that's the respective tag of file. Use Element.addEventListener() instead. Search the MDN docs pages to learn more about this methods.

Also myFunction means nothing. Name it toggleMenu or anything more descriptive. Also, avoid naming your variables with one single character like x, (well, unless you really mean x like X axis).

You can give the image a negative margin-bottom to achieve this - but you will also need to remove the overflow: hidden from the container, otherwise the image will not extend out of it, but get cut off. (Of course then you'll lose the background color here, because of the items all being floated. You will either need to use a different method to contain the floats then; or go look into more current layout methods such as flexbox to begin with.)

Something along those lines :
.imgClassName {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    }

